# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and multilabel-indicator targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm, data-science, text-classification

I have Multi class labeled text classification problem with 2000 different labels. Doing classification using LSTM with Glove Embedding.

1. Label Encoder of target variable
2. LSTM layer with Embedd Layer
3. Error metric is F2 score

#### LabelEncoded target variable:

```
le = LabelEncoder()  
le.fit(y)
train_y = le.transform(y_train)
test_y = le.transform(y_test)
```

#### LSTM network is like below with Glove Embeddings

```
np.random.seed(seed)
K.clear_session()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embed_dim, input_length = X_train.shape[1],
         weights=[embedding_matrix]))#,trainable=False
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
print(model.summary())
```

##### My error metric is F1 score. I build below function for Error metric

```
class Metrics(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []
 
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        val_predict = (np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0]))).round()
        val_targ = self.validation_data[1]
        _val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_recall = recall_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_precision = precision_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
        print("— val_f1: %f — val_precision: %f — val_recall %f" % (_val_f1, _val_precision, _val_recall))
        return
 
metrics = Metrics()
```

##Model fit is

```
model.fit(X_train, train_y, validation_data=(X_test, test_y),epochs=10, batch_size=64, callbacks=[metrics])
```

Getting below error after 1st epoch:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets
```

Where is the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

F1 score, recall and precision are metrics for binary classification for using it in a multiclass/multilabel problem you need to add a parameter to your function `f1_score`, `recall_score` and `precision_score`.

Try with this :

```
_val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
_val_recall = recall_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
_val_precision = precision_score(val_targ, val_predict, average='weighted')
```

Find more information for the average parameter here :
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html

Comment: No luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by presence of **continuous** values in val_predict in this line of code

```
_val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict)
```

You should round your predictions in val_predict before calculating f1_score.

Example solution:

```
 _val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ,np.round(val_predict))
```

Want to mention: If you want to change the threshold of the round function (0.5 default.) you can add or subtract values in [0,1] interval:

```
>>> a = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
>>> print(a, abs(np.round(a-0.1)), sep='\n')
>>> print(a, abs(np.round(a+0.3)), sep='\n')

[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
array([0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.])

[0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Hope that helps!